# Playscape Unity SDK Integration

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, playscape

We started implementing your SDK and there are approximately 30k methods and around 50 jars inside the package.
Combining that for example with Google Play services SDK, it blocks any option to add other SDK's into the game (ads, analytics ,etc...).
We noticed you have many ad networks inside the SDK (Millennial, Chartboost, etc..), can you explain what's the reason for 
those?
It seems the current SDK build is quite big for our games, how can we/you optimize it so we can move forward, please advice.

Thanks

Comment: "Your" SDK? Whom are you talking to? Also, your questions are not so clear and very broad, which is not what this site expects. Can you clarify and narrow down what you want to ask?

Comment: Igor, are you integrating playscape SDK for exchange or publishing purposes?

Comment: Fabio, sorry for the misunderstanding, I'm new stack-overflow user.
The question was addressed to specific people that understand what I'm talking about.

Comment: Sharon, currently it for exchange purposes

Answer (score 1):

Ads libraries can be excluded from apk file by perform next steps (it will also reduce the size of apk):
1. open Window->Playscape Publishing Kit Configuration... window.
2. uncheck "EnableAdsSystem" checkbox.
3. click "Apply Changes".

Ad libraries exclusion is relevant only for Playscape exchange users or other users that do not use Playscape ad mediation system.

Also you can reduce the size of google-play-services. How you can do it, described here:
[Playscape Documentation](https://github.com/Playscape/Documentation/wiki/Solving-Error---Too-many-method-references---max-is-65536)